# How does one navigate back more than one screen?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I've been trying the new Navigation component and so far so good. However, I've hit a wall when it comes to the following. My question is best described with an example, so let me give one.

I think it's a very common scenario that apps have a login screen and then they forward the user to a home screen, or dashboard, or something similar. Let's stick to the naming - `LoginScreen` and `HomeScreen`.

Say the app is very simple. It starts at the `LoginScreen` and as soon as the user logs in, they're forwarded to the `HoneScreen`. Pretty simple app, but serves the example.

Now, if the user hits back, how do we exit the app? So far it always takes me to the `LoginScreen`.

Further evolving on this example. Imagine there's a welcome screen before the login screen where the user can decide to login or register. How would one deal with navigating back in this case too?

Essentially, I'm asking if there's a built in functionality in the navigation component that let's you go back more than one screen and if not, is there a way to achieve this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Fred

To achieve this you can finish each activity after having started the other one. For example the `WelcomeScreen` has called `LoginScreen` you can directly finish it and when `LoginScreen` calls `HomeScreen` finish `LoginScreen` so when the user will navigate back from `HomeScreen` all activities will be closed.

Or, from the present activity you can call `System.exit(0)` to exit the application. This serves when you have many activities but if you have one there will be no difference with `finish()`

Another scenario is as you described in comments:
Consider you have following activities: `ActivityA`, `ActivityB` and `ActivityC` and you want to come back to `ActivityA` from `ActivityC` without passing by `ActivityB`. If you `ActivityA` has been previously opened you can bring it back to front, depending on when you want this to be done. With our sample we consider when the activity finishes:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        //this will bring the ActivityA on the front

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,ActivityA.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Or you may have a different scenario where the `LoginActivity` is started only if the is not already connected otherwise you do directly to `HomeScreen`. In this case, I create a **Singleton** that will help me register the current calling activity so that I can know which activity will be directly started after successful login.

For example:

```java
if(sharedPreferences!=null) {
                    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("user_connected",false)){
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class));}
                    else
                    {
                        MySingleton.getInstance().setCurrentCallingActivity("HomeScreen");
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
                    }
                }
```

And once in `LoginActivity`, after a successful login, I do the following:

```java
 try
                                {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(this,
                                            getClassLoader().loadClass(MySingleton.getInstance().getCurrentCallingActivity())));
                                    finish();
                                }catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                                {
                //your code
                                    finish();
                                }
```

That's how I handle that and it works. Up to you to see a corresponding scenario and try if it can work. Different approches may coexist and this far from being performant.

Comment: I understand that finishing the activity would be a way to achieve what is needed in this scenario, but as I asked, what if you want to remain in the app? Does this mean you'd have to create multiple activities?

Comment: I mean, if you have the following `ScreenA -> ScreenB -> ScreenC` and you hit back while on `ScreenC` is there a built-in way in the navigation component to go back to `ScreenA`

Comment: No no, you have to implement that yourself unfortenately. I've done this before if you want I can share the code. But within 2hours once back home

Comment: yeah, that'd be great

Comment: Sorry fo being late, I edited my answer. take a look please

Comment: thanks a lot for the contribution. I'd like to see if someone has another idea, but I'll definitely consider this. In my scenario, I meant fragments, but I case it's easily adapted.

Comment: welcome, I think you can accept it as an answer to help future readers

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
finish(); //finish LoginScreen, then when press back in HomeScreen, it will exit instead return LoginScreen
```

Comment: I understand that finishing the activity would be a way to achieve what is needed in this scenario, but as I asked, what if you want to remain in the app? Does this mean you'd have to create multiple activities?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to see if u prefer to use **Activity** or **Fragments**.

if you want to remove all **Fragments** in the stack then you need to use

```
 FragmentManager fms = getSupportFragmentManager();
 for (int i = 0; i < fms.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
                        fms.popBackStack(); }
```

If you want to remove specifc Fragment than you will have to use tags.

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);
if(fragment != null)
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```

> Now about Activity you need to consider a few options

Activity A is your Login.
Activity B is your Register page.
Activity C is your Homepage.

if you want to move from A to C after Successful login than use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

if you want to move from A to B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

if you want to move from A to B and after Register success move to C than use :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginSM.this, MainActivitySM.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and time spent. Unfortunately, I'm already aware of how to deal with those. The question is if there's a built-in way in the navigation component recently released by Google.